How to Get Azure resource topology in JSON format?
I have been trying to get the Azure resource topology in JSON format but couldn't find anything.
I tried using ARI module but there is no specific relationship mapped and there is Azure Resource visualizer but that gives output in png/jpeg/svg. In AWS you can map relationship using query in AWS Config Service.

can you provide the approach or query tried so far!

In Azure, it does not directly possible to get Azure resource topology in JSON format. There are some alternative workarounds which are detailed below to get Azure resources information in JSON format.
According to this Blog, you can below az  rest command to call the resource topology URL and retrieve the details.
az rest --method get --url "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Resources/resourceTopology?api-version=2019-10-01" --output json > topology.json

Furtherly, you can also go with the Azure Resource Graph explorer query as shown below to retrieve the resource details and also represent the formatted details in the Azure Dashboard.
resources
| project id, name, resourceGroup
| join kind=inner (resourcecontainers | project name, id) on  $left.resourceGroup == $right.name
| project id, name, parentResourceId=resourceGroup



Optionally as mentioned here in the Blog, you can use  ARM template Viewer to view the relationships between the resource group resources by exporting the ARM template from the Azure Portal. But this will not provide any JSON formatted results.
Another workaround is using the PowerShell script as shown below to retrieve the Azure resources details.
$topologylist = @()
$resourcesinfo = Get-AzResource
foreach ($res in $resourcesinfo) {
    $topology += @{
        ResourceName = $res.Name
        ResourceType = $res.ResourceType
        ParentResource = $res.ResourceId -replace "/[^/]+$", ""
        Location = $res.Location
        ResourceGroup = $res.ResourceGroupName
    }
}


